# Using VirtualBox, can I assign per-VM VPN connections/profiles, specifically in order to use different VPNs on different VMs?

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, virtual-machines, multipath

I'd like to run two VMs at the same time on the same host, with each VM connected to a different VPN connection. The host OS in question is Ubuntu, but if there is another OS which would do the job, switching could be considered.

The only option our team has suggested that would accomplish this would involve configuring the VPN using a client on the VM (Guest OS = Windows 10), which is a possibility, although for certainty's sake we would prefer to configure the connections outside the guest OS. (Reason for configuring outside the VM being to ensure the VM connects only to its VPN connection by only providing it a tunneled connection.) There is also the potential for adding VMs through automated means, which would encourage the safety of host-level network configuration, just in case something went wrong at the guest-level.

Ensuring the VM connects only to a VPN connection could be achieved by having the host OS connected to the VPN and passing the connection as a 'bridged' or 'NAT' connection, but this wouldn't allow two VMs on the same host to connect to two different VPNs.

Is this goal even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can have one bridge for each VM, where bridge consists of the VPN for the VM and the VM's network interface. However, I am not sure if VirtualBox supports this. At least VMWare Workstation Pro supports this.

Comment: Good to know, but I'm not necessarily looking to bridge for every single VM - NAT would be okay if it solves the problem.

Comment: I think a per VM bridge is the only valid approach here.